# How to set a generated key in mongodb using python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using mongodb in python. The problem I'm facing is during the generation of a key. The code through which I'm generating a key is:

post_id = posts.insert_one({msg["To"]:a}

Now here, the `"To"` consist of an email address (which consists of a symbol dot(.)). I researched few documents online and I got to knew that `“To”` of a mail cannot be used as a key, because in mongodb they use `“.(dot)”` and `“$”` as a nested document.

So now how can I proceed?

Comment: You could replace dot with some other symbol before inserting

Comment: I am not setting the key manually. it is directly coming from gmail server

Comment: E-mail address is just a string. You can come up with numerous conversions into better keys. For example, you could convert it to an md5 hash of the e-mail address.

Comment: i want the users email address as it is (something that is unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have done something like this..

'To':'test@gmail(dot)com'

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.posts.insert({'msg':{'To':'test@gmail.com'}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> 
> db.posts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d5413198cc940383264b8f"), "msg" : { "To" : "test@gmail.com" } }
```

Comment: i dont want to insert the post... i want to generate the key.

Comment: i have fetched and parsed some information now i want a key to handle that particular dictionary.

Comment: { 
 "_id" : ObjectId("56d5413198cc940383264b8f"), 
 "msg" : { 
  "_id" : ObjectId("56d5413198cc940383264b8g"), 
  "To" : "test@gmail.com" 
 }
}

Do you want like this ?